# Why does the clock work slowly at higher speed?

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation

I know nothing about relativity but I cannot accept that there is a phenomenon called [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation). However I have no problem with it because of mathematics behind it. I have no problem if time is dilated, because I don't know what time is. But I wonder when they say a clock will work slowly with respect to the other **same** clock if its speed is higher.

1. Which kind of clocks they mean? Analog clock, digital clock, etc.
2. As far as I know some mechanical clocks work by a torsion spring inside them. So, how does the material of the spring know that it must unroll slowly at higher speed? Does higher speed change chemical structure or physical properties of the material of the spring?