# How can they see 1 day and 23 years at the same time in the gravitational twin paradox of Interstellar movie?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity, earth, time-dilation

In the middle of the movie Interstellar, a crew of astronautes land on Miller's planet. For them only one day passed. For the one astronaute left in the station, 23 years passed. If we admit there is a **sun** in center of Gargantua System, what **skies** did they saw?

Once all astronautes back together, how can they know what happenend to the system (**positions of planets**)? How can 1 day happen at the same time as 23 years (of movements)?

Ask the same question on earth between altitudes of 0m and 5000m.

[Does earth rotate in a shorter time at 0m than at 5000m?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297840/does-earth-rotate-in-a-shorter-time-at-0m-than-at-5000m)

Answer (score 0):

The passing of a single day was a separate independent frame of reference from the one experiencing the passing of 23 years.

Imagine a frame of reference (a clock) falling increasingly faster into a blackhole: to an external observer (not falling into the blackhole) that clock would appear to infinitely slow, while to a person in that frame of reference time would not appear to change at all.

The difference is viewing time in one's own frame of reference vs someone else's frame of reference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50852/discussion-on-answer-by-user34445-how-can-they-see-1-day-and-23-years-at-the-sam).