# Would a supernova 1A appear to last longer if it were more distant and does it depend linearly on measured cosmological redshift?

Tags: time-dilation, distance, redshift, supernova

Would a supernova 1A appear to last longer if seen more distant and does this depend linearly on measured cosmological redshift? I asked a question on a very popular radio station where they talked about astronomy but the answer was that there is a time dilation but a weaker one....

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/674067/does-gr-explain-cosmological-time-dilation/674081#674081

Comment: @D.Halsey Yes. Thanks...