# Is my interpretation of $dt/ d\tau $ correct?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time, observers

$dt/ d\tau $ = Lorentz factor

Imagine inertial frame A is situated on a spaceship moving near the speed of light relative to inertial frame B, which is an astronaut in space. The Lorentz factor = $\frac {1 }{\sqrt{(1 - (v/c)^2)}}$ = some number greater than 1 (let's say it happens to be 5 in this case for concreteness).

If the astronaut peers into the window of the spacecraft zooming by him, he will observe clocks in the spaceship to be ticking at a factor of 5 slower than his own wrist watch. So, it makes intuitive sense that $dt/ d\tau $ is 5. The rate that the astronaut appears to be measuring his clock to tick is 5 times faster than the rate he observes the clock ticking on the spacecraft.

Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that you have to be careful about what you mean by "observe".  Each tick of the passing ship's clock comes to our astronaut's ship from a different distance, and hence with a different time delay due to the fact that information travels at a finite speed.  The correct statement is that *after correcting for these time delays*, the astronaut will say that his own clock ticks (say) five times for each tick of the passing clock.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. WillO was talking about _retarded positions_. If we disregard that your interpretation is correct. $d\tau$ is the _proper time_ (the time for the moving object), $dt$ is the observer's time, so $d\tau = dt \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$. This is for $v$ when the object is moving on the same axis with the observer's axis.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

By my reading of your question, I would say no. With the caveats suggested earlier, I would agree and say yes.

When describing what one "sees" with one's eyes, the Doppler factor $k$ is the important factor that captures the key features (not the Lorentz factor $\gamma$). The Lorentz factor $\gamma$ is only part of the story.

The following spacetime diagram may help

[image: spacetime diagram]

Two inertial observers, Alice (along AD) and Bob (along HL), will meet momentarily at event O.
In this diagram, Alice is at rest and Bob's velocity is PJ/OP=3/5 according to Alice. ( 3/5 is chosen to make the arithmetic easier and to make things easier to draw on rotated graph paper. )

The Lorentz factor (according to Alice) is the ratio OP/OJ=5/4, where Alice regards P and J as simultaneous. (By a radar experiment to measure J, Alice must send a signal at S and receive at C. Then the midpoint-event P is simultaneous with J.) You can check that for $v=3/5$, then $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}=5/4$.

[Trigonometrically, the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ is the hyperbolic cosine of the rapidity angle $\theta$ between the worldlines: (ADJACENT/HYPOTENUSE)=OP/OJ=5/4. The velocity is the hyperbolic tangent: (OPPOSITE/ADJACENT)=PJ/OP=3/5.]

What Alice "sees" (with her eyes by looking out the window) are the images of Bob's clock, as marked by the dashed lightlike lines sent from Bob's periodically ticking clock [at events H, I, O, J, K]. When Bob is approaching, Bob's clock visually appears to be running fast according to Alice: HI/AB=4/2=2. Think of Alice watching the incoming images of Bob's clock while watching her own clock.
Here's a TV transmission interpretation. If each diamond on a worldline represents 15-minutes, a 60-minute broadcast by Bob is viewed by Alice [once received] in 30 minutes. After the momentary meeting and Bob recedes, Bob's clock visually appears to be running slowly according to Alice: JK/CD=4/8=(1/2). Bob's 60-minute broadcast now takes Alice 120 minutes to view. These ratios HI/AB and JK/CD are associated with the Doppler factor $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}=2$.

[Trigonometrically, $k=\exp\theta=(\cosh\theta+\sinh\theta)=\cosh\theta(1+\tanh\theta)=\gamma(1+v)$].

(The same diagram can show that Bob would observe the same thing about Alice by drawing a different set of lightlike signals sent from a periodic sequence of Alice's ticks.)