# Time dilation on moving clocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers

Three observers are standing on Earth's surface with identical indestructible clocks.

One observer tosses his clock up such that it returns to its original height after a time T by that clock.

The second observer merely holds her clock at that height while the first observer's clock is in the air.

The third observer moves his clock so that it has constant speed as it moves up and down to the same height as the first observer's toss and moves to the original height simultaneous with the arrival of the tossed clock.

We have two effects going on here, the time dilation from special relativity, where higher speed means a slower clock, and time dilation from general relativity where a greater height above the Earth means a faster clock.

I know that the tossed clock reads the longest time but can't shew it.  I also want to find out which clock reads the shortest time and what is the time difference recorded by each clock when they return to the original height.

Comment: Hi Jay. The maths required is described [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/241794/1325) to the question [What is time dilation really?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really).