# Variation of Twin Paradox - Half Triplet Paradox

Tags: special-relativity

Here is a variation of Twin Paradox. I call it Half (for bottom half of Twin Paradox) Triplet Paradox with no change of inertial frames involved. Consider this scenario. There are triplets T1, T2 and T3. At the **Start** point their clocks are synchronized. T1 and T3 stay put hence their world line is vertical. T1 and T2 are together at **Start**. T2 moves at constant velocity and ends up with T3 at **End**. Hence T2 has a diagonal world line. **NOTE:** In this scenario none of the triplets is switching any inertial frame (unlike in Twin Paradox case).

BTW can we simply replace the triplets with stopwatches and compare the recorded time by each between **Start** and **End** and the experiment still remains the same? And using synchronization using light beams we do not have to explain how T3 got to the distant point prior to the experiment **Start**.

[image]

Obvisouly T1 and T3 are not moving with respect to each other so they will see each other aging at same rate. This allows us to compare age of T1 with T2 at **Start** and T2 with T3 at **End**.

**Questions:**

- Between **Start** and **End** will T1 and T3 see T2 aging slowly as T2 is moving at constant velocity with respect to them? Conversly will T2 see T1 and T3 aging slowly because they are moving at constant velocity away and towards T2?
- At **End** will T1 and T3 have aged more that T2?

  - If so why? Why is T2's aging different that T1 and T3's.
  - If not? Why not? What is different about this qualitatively from the Twin Paradox?

Does the answer simply boil down to how Minkowski Metric works in SR? But why does it work like that?

Comment: You're going to have problems synchronising all 3 clocks at the start because T3 is spatially separated from T1 & T2, and T2 is moving relative to T1 & T3. See [this anim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtqPQ.gif) from Wikipedia's article on the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

Comment: Homeworklike questions are generally off topic, but if you're hoping to get some help anyway, you should really indicate where you got stuck.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I think the start time was prearranged between T1 and T3 using known distance between them, the fact that they are stationary with respect to each other and light beam exchange/reflection synchronization. I think Einstein had proposed a mechanism for this to synchronize clocks across the universe using such method...if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @WillO I am not a student. I am just a scientifically literate person with interest in physics. I am trying to get that essence of time dilation and some paradox it (probably due to misunderstanding) it implies (incorrectly).

Comment: @SandipChitale Yes, T1 & T3 can use Einstein synchronisation. And T1 & T2 can synchronise at the event where T2 passes T1. But all 3 can't synchronise because T2's time axis is at an angle to T1 & T3's time axes (which are parallel). As the anim illustrates, there isn't an unambiguous "now" when you have spatially separated events, the space of simultaneity for a given observer depends on their velocity.

Comment: @SandipChitale The start time was prearranged between T1 and T3 **in their frame**. So, they will start simultaneously in their frame.. In T2's frame, T1 and T3 do not start simultaneously. It is called relativity of simultaneity. Events that are simultaneous in one frame are not simultaneous in another frame. Look up relativity of simultaneity. Once, you understand that, everything will make sense to you

Comment: The lower part of the first diagram of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462185/twin-paradox-problem-from-a-perverse-perspective is essentially your setup.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:
I noticed the first sentence and wanted to make a comment on it.

> Here is a variation of Twin Paradox. I call it Half (for bottom half of Twin Paradox) Triplet Paradox with no change of inertial frames involved.

In the scenario you described the three travelers T1, T2, and T3 from "birth" to "end" are **non-inertial.** Although they are **piecewise-inertial**, any kink in the worldline renders the traveler non-inertial [since a ball on a frictionless table in their ship will move at the kink event].
Only a traveler with a forever-straight worldline on a spacetime diagram (like one that could be drawn in the lab frame below) is inertial.

If you restrict consideration to the portion between "start" and "finish",
then they are inertial.

---

Here's a spacetime diagram on rotated graph paper
so that we can more easily read off the ticks.
The light-clock diamonds are traced out by the light-signals
in an observer's light clock.
The area of all light-clock diamonds are equal, in accordance with the principle of relativity.

I've done my best to try to model the OP's scenario.

In the following, each diamond (1 tick) represents 2.5 years.

The speeds at the initial separation are $|v|=5/13$,
which corresponds to time-dilation factor $\gamma=\frac{13}{12}\approx 1.0833$,
and Doppler factors of $k=\pm 3/2$
(rational $k$'s are associated with Pythogorean triples,
which make the arithmetic simpler).

[$k$ is an eigenvalue of the Lorentz boost and describes the reshaping of the light-clock diamond, by stretching by $k$ in the forward direction and shrinking by $k$ in the backward direction, preserving the area. (Recall the determinant of a boost is 1 and the eigenvectors are along the light cone.)]

---

[image: robphy-RRGP-halfTriplet]

You can count the ticks (each representing 2.5 years) along these piecewise-inertial worldlines.

T2 traveled at (5/9)c in order to meet T3 at T3's 30th birthday.
The lab-coordinates of events A and B are $A=(t=6.333,x=-1.666)$
and $B=(t=12.333,x=1.667)$.
T2's last leg has $\Delta x=10/3$ ticks and $\Delta t=6$ ticks in this frame.
( $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}=\frac{9}{2\sqrt{14}}\approx 1.20267$.
So, $(6/\gamma)=\frac{4\sqrt{14}}{3}\approx 4.9888$.)

Thus, T2 elapsed $\sqrt{6^2-(10/3)^2}=\sqrt{224/9}\approx 4.9888 $ ticks = $12.4722$ years.
So, T2 is $15+12.4722=27.4722$ years old
when T2 meets T3 at T3's 30th birthday.

A lab observer who is at rest and meets event B
has age 12.333 ticks $\approx 30.8333{\rm\ years}$.

I've drawn in T2's lines of simultaneity,
which are parallel to the spacelike diagonals of T2's diamonds.

Note that 4 ticks after T1 and T2 separate:

- T1 says "when 4-ticks on T1's clock have elapsed, T2 has not yet elapsed 4-ticks on T2's clock"
- T2 says "when 4-ticks on T2's clock have elapsed, T1 has not yet elapsed 4-ticks on T1's clock"

(For an elaboration of the symmetry of time-dilation, refer to my answer
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/383363/148184 
in [How can time dilation be symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383248/how-can-time-dilation-be-symmetric) )

These diagrams are based on methods described in my paper
"Relativity on Rotated Graph Paper"
Am. J. Phys. 84, 344 (2016)
https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4943251
( early draft: https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.7254 )

See also https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/relativity-rotated-graph-paper/

In addition, I mentioned
[Twin paradox problem from a perverse perspective](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462185/twin-paradox-problem-from-a-perverse-perspective) in the comment to the OP.

**Yes, this situation is due to Special Relativity.**

These diamonds are precisely traced out by the associated light clocks,
which are constructed according to the principle of relativity and the constancy of the speed of light.
From this construction visualized on a spacetime diagram,
one can likely come up with all sort of valid ways of thinking
about how these results occur (e.g. time dilations, length-contractions,
doppler effects, Lorentz transformations, etc...).

**Why is it like this?**
This is our universe as we understand it,
and is well supported by a huge amount of experimental data.
The Galilean framework with absolute time and absolute length
and its associated predictions
are not supported by experimental data, especially at high relative speeds.
Someday we may have super-high-precision watches where these effects
can be measured at lower relative speeds.

Comment: I think your statement "any kink in the worldline renders the traveler non-inertial" made me realize that at Start point there is a kink in T2s world line which is not equivalent to T1 and T3. The previous kink before the Start, even though it was a kink, was equivalent for T1, T2 (kink elbow pointing left), T3 (even though the kink elbow is pointing right but is equivalent) and hence their aging did not differ. So the key point seems to be that, if the objects have non-equivalent kinks in their history since previous rendezvous, their aging will differ. I think that is the essence, right?

Comment: @SandipChitale Consider two worldlines with different past worldlines before A (and different futures after B) but are identical along AB. Regardless of their past histories before A (and futures after B), the elapsed time along AB is the same for both. (Euclidean analogy: consider two curves in the plane that coincide along a curve from point A to B, the distances along AB are equal.)

Answer (score 1):

It is both true that T2 is aging slower in the frame of T1 and T3 and that T1 and T3 are aging slower in the frame of T2.

It is also true that when T2 and T3 meet, T2 will have aged less than T3.

How does this reconcile with the fact that T2 thinks the others are aging slower, are they just wrong? Actually, all ths is possible due to the *relativity of simultaneity*.

Notice that in a Lorenz transform, we transform the time variable:

$$ t' = \gamma (t - v x/c^2) .$$

This means that the starting point in the T2 frame, $t'=0$, is a *tilted* line in the original frame:

$$ t = v x / c^2 $$

What this essentially means is that in the T2 frame, T3 started its clock too early, and should have started it at a later time to be fair, and that's the only reason that more time has passed for T3. If T3 had started its clock when $t' = 0$, then indeed less time would have passed for T3 (T2 < T3' in the figure), because it is moving with a relative velocity to T2.

[image: twin paradox]

Comment: " _It is both true that T2 is aging faster in the frame of T1 and T3 and that T1 and T3 are aging faster in the frame of T2._ "   Shouldnt this be the other way round i.e. T2 is aging slower in the frame of T1 and T3 and T1 and T3 are aging slower in the frame of T2. When clocks are moving relative to each other, In the frame of each clock, other clocks tick **slower**, not faster

Comment: yes, fixed, ty @silverrahul

Comment: T3 Started the clock simultaneously with T1 in same inertial frame. T2 started the clock when it was with T1 at the Start.

Comment: right, but in T2's frame, T1 and T3 did not start their clocks simultaneously. T3 started its clock at an earlier time.

Comment: can this conversation be moved to [chat]  ?

Comment: @Mike Flynn I think it is not the issue of starting the clock. It is about how each triplet physically ages during the experiment. By the terms of the experiment do we agree that each triplet was of same age at the Start? Or do you not agree with it in the first place? And then we find that T3 has physically aged more than T2. That is the part I don't get.

Comment: " _By the terms of the experiment do we agree that each triplet was of same age at the Start?_ " Same age at the start **in which frame** ?.  We agree that each triplet was of same age at the start, in T1 frame. But in T2 frame, T1 and T3 were not same age at the start. This is also what mike flynn was saying in the other comment when he said " _in T2's frame, T1 and T3 did not start their clocks simultaneously_ "

Comment: @SandipChitale     Try joining this  chatroom   https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122572/twins-and-triplets-paradox

Comment: @SandipChitale they are not the same age at the start in every frame. Only in the T1/T3 frame. In the T2 frame they start at different ages.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Imagine sometime in the past T1, T2 and T3 were born as triplets at a location exactly between where T1 and T3 are at the Start point. Then to keep things symmetric T1 and T2 moved at constant speed to where T1 is at Start. T3 moved at constant speed to where T3 is at the Start. May be they even stayed there for a  while (vertical world lines for all three). Do we agree that at Start - T1 and T3 are at same physical age (yes in T1 and T3s frames)? Also T2 was right next to T1 at the Start so T1 and T2 were same physical age at the Start, right?

Comment: In T1 and T3's frame they are at the same age at the start. And in all frames T1 and T2 are the same age at the start. But in T2's frame T1 and T3 are not the same age at the start and T2 and T3 are not the same age at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I should start by saying that:

1. The two lower layers of your diagram are irrelevant- all that counts is the top layer where T2 moves relative to T1 and T3.
2. You make a misleading assumption when you say that the clocks of T1, T2, and T3 are all synchronised. I will explain this below.

The answers to your questions are as follows...

Yes, as measured by T1 and T3, T2's clock will seem to run slow, whereas in T2's frame of reference, T3's clock will seem to be running slow. The effects are entirely reciprocal.

Yes, as measured by T1 and T3, T2 will seem to have aged less than they have over the course of T2's journey. However, T2 will consider that T3 has aged less over the course of T3's journey. There is no contradiction here, but to see that there is no contradiction you must remember to take into account the fact that T2 and T3 disagree about when their respective journeys began. Both T1 and T3 believe that T2 started her journey at time T=15years. However, in T2's frame of reference, T3 began her journey at a time later than T=15years. You have mistakenly assumed that because T2 set her clock to be the same as T1's, and because T1's was synchronised with T3's, then T2's was synchronised with T3's, when it was not. T=15years on T3's watch is not simultaneous with T=15years on T2's watch  from T2's perspective.

If you have any difficulty following this, I suggest you take a simple analogy with lengths. Imagine T1 adopts one reference frame and T2 adopts another which is tilted at 45degree. T1 and T2 now each hold up a 1m stick vertically from ground level in their respective frames. Now ask yourself how 'tall' the sticks appear in each of the two reference frames. T1 will say that T2's stick is less tall than theirs because  it is tilted over. However, T2 will believe that its stick is taller because the other stick is tilted over. Each thinks the other stick is less tall because it is tilted over. There is no contradiction, we are just seeing different points of perspective.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part, we can assume that two distant stars at opposing distances were colonized by humans in previous trips, so clocks and calenders there are synchronized to the earth time.

When the twins arrive at their first destiny, if their own clocks show 10 years have passed, the destiny calender shows more than that. If their speeds were constant and equal, they now can syncronize their clocks with the stars clocks. As time goes by, they add more years over the 10 that they experience during the first trip.

When T2 meets T3 at the end of the second trip, his clock shows less time than T3 clocks. One easy way to understand it is to realize that the distance between T1 and T2 is smaller for him (length contration) than what is measured by T1 and T2. As both agree about the velocity of the ship, the time must be shorter for T2.

During the trip, it is true that T1 and T3 are aging slower than him (after all, they are moving in T2 frame). But as soon as he departs from T1 with velocity $v$, T3 is no longer syncronized to T1 *for him*. According to Lorentz transformation: $$t_3 = \gamma(t_2 - \frac{-v}{c^2}x_3)$$$$t_1 = \gamma(t_2 - \frac{-v}{c^2}x_1)$$ (according to T2 frame, T1 and T3 are moving with velocity $-v$).
As his distance $x_3$ to T3 is different from his distance $x_1$ to T1 (that is zero at the start instant), those clocks are no longer syncronized *for his frame*.

In reality, as soon the T2 trip starts, the clock of T3 shows for him a future time, compared to T1. As he approaches destiny, while T3 clock ticks all the time slower for him, T3 clock still will show a bigger time, compared to his calender.