# Gravitation time delay

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

Einstein showed us that our reality is very different from what we perceive, he taught that time under the influence of matter passes slowly. When I got to know this fact and tried to find a satisfactory explanation, I was unable to find one, all I got was more questions. It is often said that under large or compact masses time slows down and the reason provided is that as compact masses curve large amounts of spacetime and the normal distance between two points increases and to keep that speed of light constant (for a ray of light passing through a huge mass) time passes slowly when compared through different observers.

[image: gravitational time delay]

According to this image the distance between two points in spacetime gets warped and distance increases, but
SPEED =DISTANCE/TIME TAKEN then,
As the distance increases the time also must increase to keep the speed constant therefore time has to increase rather than decreasing, then how time tend to slow under higher gravitational fields?
The time per unit gets reduced but the overall time should increase in order to satisfy the speed as constant.
(I know that I am stupid somewhere.)
Thank you for your time sir/madam.

Comment: Have a look at [What is time dilation really?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really)

Answer (score 0):

Good question. But, you did little mistake on `mathematics`.

Look `Speed = distance/Time Taken`

So, if `time` increases, then `speed` decreases. And, if `distance` increases, then `speed` also increases. Because, `speed ∝ distance`

For Example:

> Speed = 10m/5s
> speed = 2m/s

If we increase the time by 2s:

> speed = 10m/7s
> speed = 1.42857142857

While time is increasing, speed is decreasing. So, if distance increase then speed will increase.

According to that picture, spacetime is getting warped for what time is decreasing and distance increasing. So, you need more speed.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir/Ma'am for your time and reply.