# Time dialtion when light travels a shorter distance compared to the observer

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

I am just starting to learn these subjects on the internet and I don't get it.

Usually, they will tell you that time just slows down when you are approaching the speed of light. They would usually rationalize it using all sorts of thought experiments, but to me, they appear logically flawed.

I usually see 2 main thought experiments. One is about 2 mirrors moving close to the speed of light so that the distance which light travels is longer. Now, because speed of light is constant, I, as an observer, would conclude that time slows down because we have a bigger $x$ but same $c$, so we must have a bigger $t$ to compensate.

Here is where my confusion starts. Why did you choose an experiment where light travels a longer distance? I can pose the same experiment differently, where the 2 mirrors are heading towards each other, so that the light on the moving mirrors would travel a shorter distance than my own resting mirrors. Wouldn't this prove just the opposite? Here, we have the same speed $c$ but shorter $x$ for the moving objects. Wouldn't I, as an observer, conclude that $t$ must be smaller?

Another experiment which I often see is about someone chasing light. What if I considered a different thought experiment where I weren't chasing light but instead running away from it?

The problem I am seeing in all of these thought experiments is that they arbitrarily choose one direction to prove that time slows down when approaching the speed of light. But how does that solve the 2 phenomena when you are heading towards it vs running away? Wouldn't "time slow down" solve it only in one scenario but not in the other?

Just as I show with the experiment of mirrors I could create a scenario which would prove that time actually goes faster. Not more slowly.

All you have to do is play with the directions. Tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You need to understand the relativity of simultaneity, as that is the source of your confusion. However, your question is not written at all clearly, so I suspect it will be closed. Try editing it again, taking more care to make the arrangements you describe clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to include a diagram of your alternative experiment with mirrors that leads to the opposite of time dilation, then we can see what you have in mind.

Comment: A tool that might help you is the [spacetime diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram).

Comment: Your last comment is far too general. You need to describe the positions and orientations of the mirrors and the light paths relative to the movements and positions of the observers, and explain why that leads you to conclude that time is contracted, not dilated, otherwise we cannot check your logic.

Comment: The very similar earlier question you asked was closed as a duplicate.  The appropriate thing to do in response to having that questions closed would be to rework it to clarify what would distinguish your answer from https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really .  Although this question is somewhat different, it still looks like it is either too vague to be adequately answered or a duplicate.

Comment: @Buzz I did exactly that and since it was close without any reason and nobody opened it even after I explained the other questions have absolutely nothing to do with mine. I opened a new one and deleted the original

Comment: @Buzz I would ask you to reopen the question.  As the other question has absolutely nothing to do with mine. Actually my question arose exactly after I read the answers to that question.  It has nothing to do with mine. They provide all sorts of experiments explanations my question asks exactly about these answers and thought experiments that are provided there

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to be sure what you have in mind, since you have not described your thought experiments with sufficient clarity. However, this might help you...

Imagine that two people, Como and Zaquette, stand together and flash a light which heads off to the right and left. After a second, the light will be 300,000,000m away from them in each direction.

Now repeat the experiment, but this time Zaquette walks after the light to the right at about 1m/s. After 1 second from Como's perspective, the light is 300,000,000m away in each direction. From Zaquette's perspective, however, the right hand beam has travelled about 299,999,999m, while the left hand beam is about 300,000,001m away. Since the speed of light is constant for Zaquette, she has to conclude that the right hand beam has travelled for slightly less than a second, while the left hand beam has travelled slightly more.

So, indeed, Zaquette's view of time in Como's frame depends on direction- in her forward direction of travel, time in Como's frame seems to have run ahead of time in hers, whereas in the reverse direction time in Como's frame seems to be running behind hers.

The effect I have described is known as the relativity of simultaneity. From it, all the other effects, such as time dilation, length contraction, the resolution to the twin paradox etc, can be explained. Unfortunately, it is an aspect of relativity that is often overlooked or misunderstood by people new to the subject, which leads to all sorts of confusion.

Note that had Zaquette walked to the left instead of the right, the effect would have been reversed in direction- time in Como's frame to the left would appear to her to be running ahead of time in Como's frame to the right. You should be able to see now why a moving clock always runs slow, because regardless of which direction Zaquette walks in, time in the stationary frame always seems to be moving ahead of her time in the direction she is headed.

The effect is symmetrical, since after a second in Zaquette's frame the light will be 300,000,000m from her in each direction, whereas Como will see that light to be 299,999,999m from him in one direction and 300,000,001m away from him in the other, so he will think Zaquette's clocks are out of synch just as she considers his to be.

The choice you mentioned of light clocks moving in a direction parallel to their length is one that is taken by many text books because it is an easy example to explain the time dilation effect, but you can take any scenario you like, and provided you think it through properly you will always arrive at the same results- if you do find yourself arriving at a result that appears at odds with SR then you will have made a mistake somewhere in your reasoning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130208/discussion-between-bilanush-and-marco-ocram).

Answer (score 0):

Einstein purposefully desingned the Einstein light clock in a certain way. A sensible way.

You purposefully designed the your light clock in a different way. Not very sensible way.

Both light clock are slower when they move.

Comment: That's exactly the question.  If the mirrors were to move towards each other. Then if they stil tick the same. That would mean V is same yet X got smaller so I just proved that T should be smaller as opposed to einstein proof. I dont understand ur answer. I edited question look if it makes more sense now

Comment: @bilanush Your clock changes with time. Very bad clock. Prove that your bad clock does not change with speed. Your bad clock speeds up slower when it moves.

Comment: Regardless of my experiment.  Why cant you create a thought experiment where X would be smaller yet light speed would still be C which forces T to change accordingly and become SMALER? I am just asking why doesnt T just change  bigger/smaller in accordance with the situation.  Wouldn't some situations force time to move faster and some situations more slowly. Based on the direction or the change of distance? How could just the fact that T slow down solve all situations either when X gets smaller or bigger

Comment: Also why does it matter if I change my clock? Suppose I dont call it a clock. Forget about einstein experiment.  No clocks involved. Just 2 mirrors heading towards each other. Now I do a basic physics equation.  X got smaller V which is speed of light C is the same. So I conclude T is smaller. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Or suppose it is a clock and instead of aligning the mirrors vertically. I want to align them horizontally.  Now suppose the mirror which is closer to me in the direction of velocity emitting light to the second /rare mirror. So the tick properly should be faster because we are running towards light. So how does V stay the same when X got smaller? Should I conclude that T is smaller?

Comment: @bilanush We are interested about time T. The time T we measure by using a clock. Einstein: "Time is what a clock measures".   You are talking about some pointless complications which I do not want to consider.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense at all. Einstein can design a clock and I can design a clock. I am allowed to do my own thought experiment so if I aligned the clocks horizontally ticking only from right to left. And I hold it and run from left to right. The lights would approach the left side faster. And so I would prove that since X is shorter yet C is constant then must be that T got smaller as well

Answer (score 0):

Thought experiments can only get you so far. Time dilation is proved by real experiments, that are performed every day e.g. in the global positioning system, and at the LHC (large hadron collider). The world really does work this way.

The thought experiments are designed to be illustrative or to give you a sense of *why* the world works some way. If you're confused by some particular thought experiment, then move on and look at other ones. There are many good online resources about relativity.

For your specific question: if you're looking at a light clock that's aligned with the direction of motion (instead of perpendicular to it) then you have to take length contraction into account as well as time dilation. It makes things much more complicated, which is why the perpendicular clock is the one usually presented in explanations.

Edited to add: as @MarcoOcram points out below, the relativity of simultaneity also must be taken into account. Not everyone will agree that two events in different places are "at the same time".

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that if I watch somebody chasing light then I would conclude T becomes smaller.  And there comes length contractions to solve it and leave T bigger. Am I right?

Comment: Ohhh ok so finally someone answers.  So the only answer to my question is that there would be a length contraction? This is the only answer so why ppl are getting mad at my question so far this is the only answer I see. As to your first point it isnt that one experiment or another confuses me..its just that I can use it to prove the opposite

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to just use intuition on the thought experiment. If you actually do the math (apply the full Lorentz transformation on both time and space coordinates of events) you will see that the orientation of the light clock doesn't matter.

Comment: But as you urself said it's only true because of the length contractions.  No? If we cut that part from the story.. indeed I am right that direction would matter no? If you are running away from light direction your time would appear to be faster to the observer